# how to Split random string with coma(,) in XSLT 1.0

Tags: string, xslt, split, xslt-1.0

I need to split string with coma and output something like below.

```
input 1:
<xsl:variable name="weekdays" select="sunday,tuesday,wednesday">

input 2:
<xsl:variable name="weekdays" select="sunday,thursday,friday,saturday">
```

Input might contain random weekdays. I need output something like below.

```
output 1:
<weekday>
sunday
Tuesday
wednesday
</weekday>

output 2:
<weekday>
sunday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
</weekday>
```

Can someone help on this.

Comment: If your variable contained a string, you could achieve the required result simply by translating the commas into line feeds. However, `<xsl:variable name="weekdays" select="sunday,tuesday,wednesday">` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Most xslt-1.0 processors support extensions, for example, exslt: http://exslt.org/str/functions/split/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, your input XML should contain the `comma` separated values in one of the elements or you will have to prepare the value of the `<xsl:variable>` accordingly. The syntax for `<xsl:variable>` shown in your question is incorrect.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<weekdays>Sunday,Tuesday,Wednesday</weekdays>
```

In the XSL, you can use a variable to hold the value from the element and use the `translate` function to replace the `comma` with the `newline` characters.

**Transformation XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="weekday-names" select="weekdays" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate($weekday-names,',','&#xA;')" />
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>Sunday
    Tuesday
    Wednesday
</output>
```